# Check two arrays have elements with same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Let's say I have arrays:

```
[0,1]
```

and

```
[1,2,3]
```

I need to verify whether these arrays have common elements, for this case it would be `1`

Using jQuery i check it following way:
**1.** get length of 1st array
**2.** get length of 2nd array
**3.** merge arrays
**4.** get length of merged array
**5.** if lenght of merged array not equal lenghts 2 initial arrays,that they have common elements

One line code is:

```
(event2Zone[0].length+event2Zone[1].length)==$.unique($.merge(event2Zone[0].zo,event2Zone[1].zo)).length
```

Is there more standard or gracefull way to do the same operation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1885557/365188

Comment: You wanted to use != instead of ==?

Comment: i think it does't matter what flag is returned

Comment: One liner: ECMA5: `a.some(function(v) { return b.indexOf(v) !== -1; })`

Comment: @sergionni https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some - Returns `true` if any truly values is returned from the loops. Else returns `false`.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. This question is asking how to **test if** any intersection exists between two arrays. The linked question asks **to find the intersecting values**. There might be an answer that solves this question, but doesn't return the values (like the examples given in the question based on `length`). Voting to reopen.

Comment: (also re. the jQuery examples given, note that ["jQuery.unique() only works on arrays of DOM elements, **not strings or numbers**"](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/) ) - it does sometimes work, but [can't be relied on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191941/jquery-unique-on-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: `const hasIntersection = (a, b) => a.some(v => b.includes(v));` ES6 using @andlrc I think marking this as duplicate is wrong since the other question is about `getIntersetction` and not `hasIntersection` which are 2 differnet solutions