# jQuery - remove duplicates from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, unique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)
>   [jQuery.unique on an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191941/jquery-unique-on-an-array-of-strings)

I'm trying to get a neighbor list by breadth-first search (to be specific: the indexes of same color neighbor balls in [Block'd](http://www.gameguru.in/images/block-d-ss2.jpg))
my `function getWholeList(ballid)` return an array like

```
thelist=["ball_1","ball_13","ball_23","ball_1"]
```

and of course there are duplicates.

I tried to remove them with jQuery.unique(); but it does not work with strings I guess,
so is there any way for this(making the array unique) ?

Thanks for any help..

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array

Comment: @kleinohad: Just mark it as a duplicate

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I found the required function in
[this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191941/jquery-unique-on-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: for me $.unique it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/8RNYF/

Answer (score 79):

The jQuery [`unique` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) only works on an array of DOM elements.

You can easily make your own uniqe function using the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) methods:

```
function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  return result;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Askwb/

Comment: using `grep` is also good:
`function unique(list) {
    return $.grep(list, function(n, i) {
            return list.indexOf(n) == i;
    });
}`

Answer (score 15):

As a non jquery solution you could use the Arrays `filter` method like this:

```
var thelist=["ball_1","ball_13","ball_23","ball_1"], 
    thelistunique = thelist.filter(
                 function(a){if (!this[a]) {this[a] = 1; return a;}},
                 {}
                );
//=> thelistunique = ["ball_1", "ball_13", "ball_23"]
```

As extension to `Array.prototype` (using a shortened `filter` callback)

```
Array.prototype.uniq = function(){
  return this.filter(
      function(a){return !this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;}, {}
  );
}
thelistUnique = thelist.uniq(); //=> ["ball_1", "ball_13", "ball_23"]
```

[**Edit 2017**] An ES6 take on this could be:

```js
const unique = arr => [...new Set(arr)];
const someArr = ["ball_1","ball_13","ball_23","ball_1", "ball_13", "ball_1" ];
console.log( unique(someArr) );
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this one - [Array.unique()](http://www.jslab.dk/library/Array.unique)

```
Array.prototype.unique =
  function() {
    var a = [];
    var l = this.length;
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
      for(var j=i+1; j<l; j++) {
        // If this[i] is found later in the array
        if (this[i] === this[j])
          j = ++i;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
    }
    return a;
  };
thelist=["ball_1","ball_13","ball_23","ball_1"]
thelist=thelist.unique()
```

Comment: don't try this on large arrays though, this has quadratic complexity

Comment: doesn't this also sort the array? Sometimes this is unwanted

Answer (score 2):

There is a JavaScript port of the PHP `array_unique` function here: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_unique

```
function array_unique (inputArr) {
    var key = '',
        tmp_arr2 = {},
        val = '';

    var __array_search = function (needle, haystack) {
        var fkey = '';
        for (fkey in haystack) {
            if (haystack.hasOwnProperty(fkey)) {
                if ((haystack[fkey] + '') === (needle + '')) {
                    return fkey;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    for (key in inputArr) {
        if (inputArr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            val = inputArr[key];
            if (false === __array_search(val, tmp_arr2)) {
                tmp_arr2[key] = val;
            }
        }
    }

    return tmp_arr2;
}
```

Or as of later JS:

```
arr.filter((v, p) => arr.indexOf(v) == p)
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.unique() only works for array of DOM elements. Take a look at this (enhanced version of unique) :

[Enhanced unique](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/)