# How to add values as a list in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I use the following to add values to local storage:

```js
var thisId = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
localStorage.setItem("postId", thisId);
console.log(localStorage.getItem("postId"));
```

The following is **loaded for each page i end up in, every time**:

```
<?php echo $id; ?>
```

So it will become: `242` or `248` etc

Thing is each time I do `console.log(localStorage.getItem("postId"));` i only get one value as it is not adding as a list of values but replacing the old with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to wait for all document components to be loaded, and after that you can insert your PHP value directly into the lcoalStorage. Be careful though, localStorage can ONLY contain simple variable, no objects or arrays. If you want to store an object or array, be sure to `stringify` it before saving it.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
    localStorage.setItem("postIdList", JSON.stringify ("<?=$idList?>") );
    console.log( JSON.parse ( localStorage.getItem("postIdList") ) );
});
```

EDIT. 
Here's an example of how to convert a PHP array to JSON and from there store it in the localStorage and convert it back to JSON.

```
<?php
$listIds = [1,2,5];
$jsonIds = json_encode( $listIds );
?>
<script>
    localStorage.setItem( "myIds", "<?=$jsonIds?>" );
    console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( "myIds" ) ) );
</script>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan exactly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan with the exception that I actually explain OP can't store objects/arrays in localStorage.

Comment: Then it would help if you showed the OP the code to do that, as your current sample is just echoing their question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Edited. Also edited variables since they implied single values, not arrays or objects.

Comment: @rob.m why not just save the list under a single variable? Now you'll have to iterate through different key names to get the values. You COULD json_encode($list) and directly insert it into the localStorage. That would be much faster.

Comment: @BRO_THOM yeah that's actually a better logic, i'll try it out, thanks

Comment: @rob.m if you want, I could expand my answer above to fit that example?

Comment: @BRO_THOM yes that'd be awesome

Comment: @rob.m I've updated my answer. Check the second section for an example of how to convert PHP arrays to JSON and back to a Javascript array.

Comment: The array with the id list won't be generated form the same page, each time we end in a page, I am saving the id into the array, so adding to it. I need to use the unique function for the array tho as I could land on the same page and we wouldn't want to add the same id to the array if already present

Comment: @rob.m you can simply use this example to get (JSON.parse) the current value, add an id using the `push` method, and after that set (JSON.stringify) it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167724/discussion-between-rob-m-and-bro-thom).

Answer (score 4):

Use a list instead. As you can only store **Strings** into localStorage, the best approach is to use JSON parse/stringify methods to help you with data serialization.

- Get the localstorage item as a list (JSON.parse)
- Add the item
- Save the list into localstorage (JSON.stringify)

```html
var thisId = "1";//<?php echo $id; ?>

var localList = localStorage.getItem("postIdList") || "[]";
localList = JSON.parse(localList);

//Check repeated ID
var isExistingId = localList.indexOf(thisId) > -1;
if (!isExistingId) {
  localList.push(thisId);
}

localStorage.setItem("postIdList", JSON.stringify(localList));
console.log(localStorage.getItem("postIdList"));
```

Comment: could provide a code example instead of a conceptual logic? Saying this for future users too ending up on here

Comment: thanks a lot for the code, it's a bit broken when I run the snippet but i get the idea, thank you

Answer (score 0):

setItem replace the string correspondent to that specific key if present.
As suggested in the other answer fetch the current array of values update it and stringify it.

make sure to wrap the code in a try catch since json.parse could potentially raise an exception

```
try{
   let currentArray = Array.isArray(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("postId"))) 
     ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("postId")) 
     : [];
   currentArray.push(thisId);
   localStorage.setItem("postId", JSON.stringify(currentArray));
}
catch(err){
   localStorage.setItem("postId", "[]");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Answer (score 0):

Below is a really simple example that add random number to a list, you can just alter to suite your needs..

```
//first get current lines
var lines = localStorage.getItem("lines") ?
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")) : []; 

//lets add a random number to the list
lines.push(Math.random()); 
console.log(lines); 

//now lets save our new list
localStorage.setItem("lines", JSON.stringify(lines));
```

Comment: mmm what happens tho is that each time i load it will create a new array

Comment: this is the final using your answer    `var thisId = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
    var lines = localStorage.getItem("lines") ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")) : []; 
    var myIdString = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines"));
    lines.push(thisId);
    function unique(list) {
      var result = [];
      $.each(list, function(i, e) {
          if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
      });
      return result;
    }
    console.log(unique(lines));`

Comment: not sure if I should accepting your answer tho, maybe I add to mine as yours is incomplete, as I did say a new id to the list when I load the page

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/6e21wtc9/1/)

localStorage only supports strings so.

```
var id = [];// For sample
id[0] ="1";
id[1] ="2";
localStorage.setItem("ids", JSON.stringify(id));
var storedIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ids"));
console.log(storedIds);
```

Comment: this is nice so basically     `var thisId = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
    var id = [];
    id.push(thisId);`

Comment: Yap Happy coding :)

Comment: mmm what happens tho is that each time i load it will create a new array

Comment: According to this old answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values local storage have some limits so try to reuse  array rather than create new every time or remove old one and create new one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most beautiful and it'd become very long if more than two are needed, but this is A solution.

So basically i create two localStorage and I first check if they are empty and if the key isn't the same as per the variable I am setting, and do this each time I load the page.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("idA")) {
  var thisId = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
  localStorage.setItem("idA", thisId);
  console.log("A " + localStorage.getItem("idA"));
} else {
  console.log("A " + localStorage.getItem("idA"));  
}
if(localStorage.getItem("idA") != "<?php echo $id; ?>") {
  if(!localStorage.getItem("idB")) {
    var thisId = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
    localStorage.setItem("idB", thisId);
    console.log("B " + localStorage.getItem("idB"));
  } else {
    console.log("A " + localStorage.getItem("idA"));  
    console.log("B " + localStorage.getItem("idB"));
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Keith Answer, to add unique values ([see this reply on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12551709/1018804)), this is what I did:

```
var thisId = "<?php echo $id; ?>"; 
var lines = localStorage.getItem("lines") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")) : []; 
var myIdString = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")); 
lines.push(thisId); 
function unique(list) { var result = []; 
$.each(list, function(i, e) { 
  if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e); }); 
  return result; 
} 
console.log(unique(lines));
```

Comment: In what way is this a better approach than just using the 1 localeStorage slot, and JSON.stringify / parse, like everybody else mentioned?..  This approach seems very inflexible, and gains you nothing compared to 1 localeStorage item..

Comment: it is not flexible indeed and it is NOT absolutely the best solution. What happen is that `var thisId = "<?php echo $id; ?>";` is a new ID set on each page load, i understand the jSon string trick, however, each time I load the page, the values are added, so the other answers would replace the values on each page load, not adding to it

Comment: @Keith see your `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")) : [];` is created each time we page load

Comment: It's created if it doesn't exist, otherwise it loads it from localStorage.  If you ran the code of mine inside say Chromes console, every time you run it a random number is added to the list,.. Refresh the browser, and the list will continue from were it left off etc.  Is this not what your after?

Comment: let me try it, might work, haven't actually tried yours. I was also thinking of using `contains` and add the new `string` (thanks to the `JSON.stringify / parse` trick) if is not there

Comment: i confirm, each time i reload the same page, using your bit, i get the old value added again, resulting in duplicated values `(2) ["248", "248"]`, probably I could use `contains`, will try it now

Comment: Yes, I did say if you alter to fit your needs, if you want unique id's adding to the list, it's the same approach.  btw.  it's `includes`, not `contains`.. eg.  `JSON.parse('["one", "two"]').includes("two")` etc.

Comment: @Keith ok i made it work using your answer but I had to use array unique, following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12551709/1018804 then this `console.log(unique(lines));`

Comment: JSON.parse could potentially raise an exception (either if the key is not defined or if the user change the value) , i'd suggest wrapping the code in a try catch block, and if any error is raise initialize the key to an empty array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511011/how-to-add-values-as-a-list-in-localstorage/49512756#answer-49511284