# jQuery.unique does not work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

```
positions_list = [
  "M.pharm", 
  "pharmaceutical sales", 
  "pharmacist", 
  "druggist", 
  "MPharm", 
  "pharmaceutical sales", 
  "pharmacist", 
  "druggist", 
  "MPharm"
];
```

Then with `jQuery.unique(positions_list);` I get this result in Google Chrome (56.X):

```
["M.pharm", "pharmaceutical sales", "pharmacist", "druggist", "MPharm"]
```

However the result in MS Edge is this:

```
["M.pharm", "pharmaceutical sales", "pharmacist", "druggist", "MPharm", "pharmaceutical sales", "pharmacist", "druggist", "MPharm"]
```

As you can see the result in MS Edge is the same as the original list. How can I de-duplicate list in MS Edge?

Comment: I'd suggest raising this as a bug with jQuery if you can consistently reproduce it.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: @Viplock no errors, just the same result as the original.

Comment: Did you try what they suggest on this post ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962759/jquery-unique-function-not-working-properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962759/jquery-unique-function-not-working-properly)

Comment: @BrentBoden life-saver! Because the description of the `unique` in the docs is gray, I totally missed it. With the custom function it works in both browsers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the [jQuery.unique() doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) (referenced by @Brian Graham in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19963011/2112089) answer, itself referenced by @Brent Boden in comments):

> **Description:** Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.