# How do I modify this and return this, employing a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, jquery-plugins, this

I have a jQuery plugin, which I created with partial help looking at this thread: [jQuery.unique on an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191941/jquery-unique-on-an-array-of-strings).

Here is my code:

```
// function
$(function() {
    $.fn.removeDuplicates = function() {
        var arrResult = [];
        for (var i = 0, n = this.length; i < n; i++) {
            var item = this[i];
            var index = item.SerialNo + " - " + item.UPC + " - " + item.Name + " - " + item.Version + " - " + item.Description;
            arrResult[ index ] = item;
        }
        var i = 0;
        var nonDuplicatedArray = [];
        for (var item in arrResult) {
            nonDuplicatedArray[i++] = arrResult[item];
        }
        return (this = nonDuplicatedArray);
    };
});

var arrObj = [
    { "SerialNo:"1234", "UPC":"ABCXYZ", "Name":"Test", "Version":"1", "Description":"test"}, 
    { "SerialNo:"1234", "UPC":"ABCXYZ", "Name":"Test", "Version":"1", "Description":"test"}, 
    { "SerialNo:"12345", "UPC":"ABCXYZ123", "Name":"Test2", "Version":"2", "Description":"test2"} 
];

$(arrObj).removeDuplicates();
```

I want to modify `this` and return it. The plugin doesn't have to be chained, but I want to keep the function call the same. I realize I can modify the function by returning `nonDuplicatedArray` and set it to a variable in the function call, ergo:

```
var newVar = $(arrObj).removeDuplicates();
```

But I was hoping there's a way to directly modify `this` inside the function and return `this`, while preserving the original function call. Simply, how do I set `nonDuplicatedArray` to `this`?

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't really seem like the kind of thing you'd use a jQuery plugin for, passing an array as the selector etc ?

Comment: I'd love to be educated. Why wouldn't I use a jQuery plugin in this case? I'm being sincere. Maybe you're right.

Comment: You're changing an array, something you could just use a function for. jQuery is usually used for manipulating the DOM, and passing an array to have a jQuery plugin that just changes the array and returns it seems like a bad use of jQuery as it would be even easier to just use a regular function.

Comment: Yeah, I think what you're saying makes a lot of sense. What you're saying I would better off doing something like creating an array prototype function, instead of using a JS framework.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, and at the same time prototyping on native objects like Array is not always a good idea either, but in this case it seems like a much better idea than using jQuery.

Comment: Good to know. I'll take that to heart. Thank you for the knowledge transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, just return the array, there's no need to set `this` to `nonDuplicatedArray` once the function has done what it's supposed to do, you no longer need the `this` keyword, you just need to return the array  ?

```
return nonDuplicatedArray;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jZ46P/)

Comment: Ah. So, the original variable, `arrObj`, will be modified by returning `nonDuplicatedArray`? I don't have to set it to something like `newVar`? Actually, according to the fiddle, the return is setting to a new variable. What I want to do is not have to do that.

Comment: @user717236 - If you're going to chain it, you'd have to wrap it, as in `return $(nonDuplicatedArray);` but then you have a jQuery object containing the array. I returned the array somewhere to console log it, but you don't have to do that. Here's an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/jZ46P/1/

Comment: Or without chaining, and just returning the array -> http://jsfiddle.net/jZ46P/2/

Comment: Whatever you return is now the value.

Comment: Oh OK. I see now. That makes perfect sense. Thank you for your help and the education!